# How does Postgres manages case-sensitive versus case-insensitive “IN” operations in Entity Queries?

Tags: entities

I see that an equality is converted to a LIKE operation when the field is tagged as case-insensitive, which Postgres then translates to ILIKE in the driver. However, I don’t see how Postgres is able to do both case sensitive and case insensitive IN comparisons.

The same black magic occurs with the STARTS_WITH, and CONTAINS operators.